# Isosceles Triangle With Height Limiting To Zero

Tags: calculus, limits

The figure shows an isosceles triangle $ABC$ with $\angle B = \angle C$ . The bisector of angle $B$
intersects the side $AC$ at the point $P$. Suppose that the base $BC$ remains fixed but the
altitude $|AM|$ of the triangle approaches $0$, so $A$ approaches the midpoint $M$ of $BC$. What
happens to $P$ during this process? Does it have a limiting position? If so, find it.

[image]

I have tried relating $P$ and $A$ in a few ways(the law of cosines being one them) but I fail at finding something that gives me an equation for the position of P.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $A\to M$, $P$ gets closer to lying on $BC$. Now we only need to find limit of $CP$ as $AC\to \frac{BC}{2}$.

Hint: Use Angle Bisector Theorem to find $CP$ in terms of $AC$ and $BC$.

Comment: Okay I got this from your hint: $\frac{CP}{AP} = \frac{BC}{AB} \Leftrightarrow CP = \frac{(BC)(AP)}{AB}$ since $AB = AC \Rightarrow CP = \frac{(BC)(AP)}{AC}$. Now how do I get rid of that $AP$ in order to take the limit $AC \to \frac{BC}{2}$?

Comment: well, $AP=AC-CP$.

Comment: Oh right, my mistake. So the result of the limit $\lim_{AC \to \frac{BC}{2}} CP = \frac{BC}{3}$

Comment: Yes, from that can you tell the position of the limit of $P$?

Comment: So I can conclude that P ends up one third the distance of $BC$ from $B$ between $B$ and $C$?

Comment: @KermittheHermit: Yes.

Comment: Great, this was fun. Thanks, Quang Hoang, I really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Taking $B=(0,0)$ and $C=(0,1)$ leaves $A=\frac12(1,\tan\beta)$, where $\beta$ is the corner at $B$. Simple equations give me that the point $P$ has coordinates $(x_0,y_0)$, where

$$x_0=\frac{\tan\alpha}{\tan\frac\alpha2 + \tan\alpha}$$
so it is easy to calculate the limit of $x_0$ as $\alpha\to0.$

Answer (score 1):

Take M as the origin, B as $(-x, 0)$, C as $(x, 0)$. Let tan of angle PBC be t. Then A = $(\frac{2t}{1-t^2},0)$. Solving relevant equations gives x coordinate of P as $\frac{(1+t^2)x}{3-t^2}$. As t goes to 0 this goes to $x/3$.