# Isosceles Triangle with height that limits to zero

Tags: calculus, limits

The figure shows an isosceles triangle $ABC$ with $\angle B =\angle C$. The bisector of angle $B$ intersects the side $AC$ at the point $P$. Suppose that the base $BC$ remains fixed but the altitude $|AM|$ of the triangle approaches $0$, so A approaches the midpoint $M$ of $BC$. What happens to $P$ during this process? Does it have a limiting position? If so, find it.

[image: Isosceles triangle]

This question has been asked before but I wasn't able to track with the explanation. I don't understand where to go when identifying what $CP$ is equal to. I have $CP = [BC(AC - CP)]/AC $ and I got that with the angle bisector theorem but I'm not sure what's after that. [og post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881542/isosceles-triangle-with-height-limiting-to-zero)

Comment: Just use trig.  $BM$ is constant.  $BM= \cos \angle B\times BA$ and $BM = \sin \angle B\times BA$.  If we project $P$ to the base to $K$ and look at the intersection of $BP$ and $AM$ at $N$ then we have $\sin \frac 12 \angle B \times BN=PN$ and $\sin \frac 12 \angle B \times BP = PK$ and $\cos \frac 12 \angle B\times BM = AM$.  Solve for $PH$ and $KN$ should be straightforward.

Comment: From $CP = [BC(AC-CP)]/AC$, at the limit $BC/AC = 2$. Then solve $CP = 2AC - 2CP$ to find $CP$.

Comment: @peterwhy  could you elaborate on the BC/AC = 2 part? That's what I'm not really tracking.

Comment: As you said, "$A$ approaches the midpoint $M$ of $BC$". Then at the limit $BC/AC = 2$.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the image of the triangle at the limit just wasn't clicking in my head, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

since point $A$ is approaching $M$ it is obvious that the angle $BAC$ is approaching $\pi$ radians and therefore the angles $B$ and $C$ shrink to zero.
now draw a perpendicular line to $BC$ from $P$ suppose it intersects $BC$ at H with shrinking the angle BC, PBH also shrinks to zero since we have
$\sin x \approx_{x\rightarrow 0} x$;
$PH$ also shrinks to zero therefore point $P$ falls on the line $BAC$.

Comment: How does knowing P being on the line BAC show limiting position? How would I transform this information into some sort of limit?

Comment: you need to derive the distance of P from the line BC as a function of an angle in the triangle that is having a limiting behavior; and that is exactly what we did.